# Unable to apply SSL certificate to Reporting Server 2014

Tags: reporting-services, ssl-certificate, sql-server-2014

I am trying to apply SSL certificate to Reporting server. I have added my certificate **mmc.exe>Add/Remove Snap-in>Certificates>Computer Account>Local Computer>Finish**
Now, I can see certificate under **Console root>Certificates>Personal>Certificates**
Certificate info like following:

```
Issued To : xyz.com
Issuded By : abc-CA
Expiration Date : 11/11/2018
Intended Purpose: Server Authentication,client authentication
Certificate Template: Computer (3 year)
```

To apply certificate, I did following:

```
 1. Opened Reporting service configuration manager
 2. Web Service URL
 3. But Under "SSL Certificate", I don't see the certificate.
```

Please guide me, how should I get it?
I tried almost everything but no luck.

I got following link on same.
http://blogs.technet.com/b/configurationmgr/archive/2014/07/23/a-step-by-step-example-of-configuring-a-reporting-services-point-for-https-in-system-center-2012-configuration-manager.aspx

Thanks

Comment: Have you imported the certificate with the private key also?  You should be able to tell this if you look in the MMC console and look at the certificate icon, does it have a little key next to the picture of the certificate or is it just the certificate?

Comment: Yes. Certificate with the private key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got solution, actually Certificate was missing "Subject Name", hence it was not coming to Report server configuration manager.